# Rewrite URL into shorter

Tags: .htaccess, url, url-rewriting

Currently my website does this when you go to whoever's profile:

> index.php?a=profile&u=berdyev

I would like to make it look like:

> website.com/berdyev

Any suggestions?

Thank you.

Comment: base everything on the index page through case/database pull, et al.

Answer (score 1):

Place this in your root .htaccess:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/?$ /index.php?a=profile&u=$1 [L,QSA]
```